# How to comment near environment variable in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

In my colab notebook I would like add some custom parameters and for this I need `#@param ecc` near to them.

I'm using Jupyter magic commands environment variable `%env` and the system takes the whole line (comment included) and not only the variable.  This results in an error.  I guess it's not possible to comment next to `%env` magic variables, or is there a way?

I'm doing this:

```
%env checkpoint_iter = 50
%env content_weight =  8 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:100, step:0.1} #@markdown Weight of content image

 !python -W ignore main.py ${checkpoint_iter} ${content_weight}
```

And then I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    checkpoint_iter = int(sys.argv[9])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#@param'
```

My my goal would be to get something like this:

[image: my goal]

How can I reach this?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but have you checked Jupyter Widgets? https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @medium-dimensional I tried...but it doesn't take "w.value" like a code but like a string...all after %env I guess it can't be code, only int or float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not comment inside Collab forms.

But you can combine a comment, slider and env. variable like this:

```
#@markdown Checkpoint iteration
checkpoint_iter = 30 #@param {type:"integer"}
%env checkpoint_iter = $checkpoint_iter

#@markdown Weight of content image
content_weight =  21.4 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:100, step:0.1}
%env content_weight = $content_weight
```

By the way, you don't have to use environmental variables to pass command line parameters. Using variable reference `$<var_name>` should work the same:

```
weight =  86.5 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:100, step:0.1}
iter = 50

!python -W ignore main.py $iter $weight
```